# Load image from project file into ImageSource with Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, imagesource

Have a local folder with images (app/resources/mock/images). This folder contains images which are used when the app is generated to read mock services.

**Need to load an image from that folder into an ImageSource file**, which then I send to a mocking method which downloads to the file disk (saveToFile) so it can be viewed. But have not found a way to do that.

***ImageSoure.loadFromFile***: Will load image from already saved images in file system (not finding them: FileNotFoundException)

***ImageSource.fromResource***: Requires to put images in the resources folder which is then included in the APK

This is not loading the image:

> ```
> let image = new ImageSource();
> let result = image.loadFromFile("../resources/mock/images/test-image.jpg");
> ```

How could I do it of is there any other better way to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use relative path for images. Depending on your project structure, `"~/resources/mock/images/test-image.jpg"` or `"~/app/resources/mock/images/test-image.jpg"` should work.

Comment: thanks, I didn´t realize that, just tested without problems

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your usage of `loadFromFile`. I have used `fromFile` in the past:

```
import { fromFile, ImageSource } from 'tns-core-modules/image-source/image-source';

let image: ImageSource = fromFile('~/resources/mock/images/test-image.jpg');
```